# How can I use Maxima to obtain individual iterations of Newton's method?

Tags: maxima-software

I'm using Maxima with the following calculation:

```
mnewton([
        (x-15600)^2+(y-7540)^2+(z-20140)^2-((2.998*10^5)*(-t+0.07074))^2,
        (x-18760)^2+(y-2750)^2+(z-18610)^2-((2.998*10^5)*(-t+0.07220))^2,
        (x-17610)^2+(y-14630)^2+(z-13480)^2-((2.998*10^5)*(-t+0.07690))^2,
        (x-19170)^2+(y-610)^2+(z-18390)^2-((2.998*10^5)*(-t+0.07242))^2
    ], [x,y,z,t],[1,1,1,1]);
```

This completes the iterations successfully and stabilises after about 10. This is great, but I want to be able list each iteration until it stabilises for a report I'm doing.

I tried changing the newtonmaxiter variable to 1, but it just comes up with the following when I put in the above calculation:

```
"mnewton: the process doesn't converge or it converges too slowly."
```

It also does this for 5, but at 10 is gives me the answer. Is there a way I can get the iterations BEFORE they converge?

Comment: You can use Wolfram|Alpha for that. It is much easier there.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas How would I go about doing the second, third, fourth, etc, iterations on WolframAlpha? It's too messy to put in all the values from one iteration into the next.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they list out all the iterations and results at each step. I maybe wrong though.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Do you know what I'd have to input to get Wolfram to do Newton's method?

Comment: "solve <equation here> using Newton's Method". [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2^x%2Bx^2%3D0+by+Newton%27s+Method)'s an input sample. Click on the "Show Details" or "More" button in the "Steps" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading https://github.com/andrejv/maxima/blob/master/share/mnewton/mnewton.mac you will find that there is a parameter `newtondebug`, setting it to `true$` will print out the information you required.

Comment: You're a legend mate, this is exactly what I was after. Cheers.